# Expectation Maximization for Urn Problem

Tags: hidden-markov-model, expectation-maximization

I am currently investigating the following mental exercise:

- An urn is filled with N balls. Each ball possesses a number and it is either red or green.
- There are M color detectors. Each detector possesses a number and they tell whether a ball inserted is either red or green. If used, a color detector always provides an answer however sometimes this answer is wrong meaning there are two conditional probabilities $P(\textrm{detector says red}|\textrm{ball inserted is red})$ and $P(\textrm{detector says green}|\textrm{ball inserted is green})$ associated with each detector.

Now the following procedure is repeated over and over again: without looking at the color, a ball is taken out of the urn at random and inserted into a random detector. The detection result is noted down and the ball is put back into the urn. In this way a table is obtained similar to the following example:

```
| Ball Identifier | Detector Identifier | Detection Result |
|               1 |                   1 | red              |
|               2 |                   2 | green            |
|               4 |                   2 | red              |
|               1 |                   1 | green            |
|               3 |                   2 | green            |
|               1 |                   2 | red              |
|             ... |                 ... | ...              |
```

**My question is: is it possible by using such a table, to estimate both the detection probabilities and the true color of the balls?**

I already considered the following topics:

- The problem resembles a Hidden Markov model. But in contrast to those, there are no state transitions here.
- I was also thinking about using an Expectation Maximization algorithm. However I could not recognize a likelihood function with free parameters.

Could anybody point me to a right direction? Any help is appreciated.

**Question and Answers**

**1. How is the detector identifier created?**

The detector identifier is just a unique number to distinguish the detectors. Similar to that, the ball identifier is unique number to distinguish the balls from each other.

**2. Is the misclassification random noise?**

Yes, in case a red ball is inserted it says red with probability $P(\textrm{detector says red}|\textrm{ball inserted is red})$ and green with probability $1 - P(\textrm{detector says red}|\textrm{ball inserted is red})$. In case a green ball is inserted it says green with probability $P(\textrm{detector says green}|\textrm{ball inserted is green})$ and red with probability $1 - P(\textrm{detector says green}|\textrm{ball inserted is green})$. In addition, the detection result does not depend on whether the ball was already inserted previously in the same detector or not.

**3. Do you know what proportion of the Urn is red/green?**

The exact proportion is not known.

Comment: 1. How is the detector identifier created? 2. Is the misclassification random noise? 3. Do you know what proportion of the Urn is red/green?